# Метод, который позволяет установить режим fullscreen для проигрываемого видео

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток! У меня есть кастомный videoview,всё работает отлично, но возникла необходимость в том, чтобы пользователь при нажатии на кнопку мог устанавливать режим fullscreen для воспроизводимого видео. Есть ли какие нибудь методы, позволяющие этот режим задать программно? И какой из этих способов можно использовать(если, конечно, можно)?

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

или:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

или:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Вопрос закрыт

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776254/android-video-view-in-fullscreen Далее, просто пробуете, то что подойдет в вашей ситуации, ибо логику то вашего кода никто не знает.

Comment: Спасибо,я уже решил вопрос по-другому. Я-то гуглил, просто не знал, что конкретно лучше использовать.

Comment: Использовать то, что работает в вашей ситуации. Или тему менять или просто растягивать макет, убирая все плашки(если есть).

Comment: я макет растягивал